# LIBSVM parameter selection

Tags: parameters, svm, libsvm

I’m working on a system that can optimize parameters of SVM (LIBSVM toolbox) and best features (inputs) together. My optimization techniques is harmony search or genetic algorithm. I normalized data before insert it to system ( Maxmin or whitening) so as you know I must set

```
-g gamma : set gamma in kernel function 
-c cost : set the parameter C of C-SVC, epsilon-SVR, and nu-SVR
```

I have a binary classification problem with financial database. Besides it sometimes I’m using dimension reduction techniques like “PCA” and other techniques.

So what is your proposed searching intervals for gamma and cost parameters?

Second question : What other parameters of LIBSVM do you think i should optimize with my optimization technique?

Thanks.

**PS.** My kernel function is "RBF"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what is your proposed searching intervals for gamma and cost parameters?

Basically, you should do a heuristic grid search by taking some educated guesses at the grid cell sizes, hoping to find a good optimum. Take a look in the Grid.py file in the LIBSVM package. It will give you some hints regarding these values. There are more advanced techniques for doing this, but this is the first thing worth trying.

> Second question : What other parameters of LIBSVM do you think i should optimize with my optimization technique?

This depends on the kernel that you choose. Note that gamma doesn't impact all kernel types (like, for example, the linear one). There may be other things that you can try to tweak, but start with these two and see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you have a brief describe about grid search? I’m not familiar with it. I should only set two values (lower and upper) for every parameter interval in my optimization algorithm.
Thanks.

Comment: "Note that C and / or gamma don't impact all kernel types " look like a bad wording. **C** impacts each "kernel type" as it is a SVM parameter, not the kernel parameter.

Comment: @leilot that's true  lejlot. I should mention it in main question. My kernel function is "RBF". I think I have higher classification accuracy with it.

Comment: @lejlot Indeed, C is a SVM parameter. I corrected my answer.

Comment: @user2991243 If you look in Grid.py, you'll see that it generates an array of values for gamma and one for C and then it tries each combination of values to see which pair gives the best accuracy. There is an extension [over here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/eval/index.html) which allows you to use other criteria, if needed. I do not know how they picked those particular values, but I assume that they give good results in most cases. Andrew Ng also provides some intuition on how to pick these values during his [Coursera](http://www.coursera.org/course/ml) lectures.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you looking at the tutorial provided by Dr. Lin [Tips and tricks for liblinear](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/liblinear.pdf) . Unless you have a very strong justification of using a specific kernel try with all available kernels. Again, I would try training/testing with un-normalized/unscaled data too. Remember these (scaling) are heuristics, no one knows what would be the set of params for your requirement. Explore all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found in Dr. Lin document that he used {-2^14 2^14} for C but because linear kernel We don't have Sigma for "RBF" in this code. So what is your suggestion for this parameter?

Comment: @user2991243 Try from 10^-1 to 10^5, in steps of multiple of 10.

Comment: Why your range is more positive? Why you didn't select [10^(-5) 10^5] ? another problem. I can search in steps of multiple of 10. My algorithm search all values between these two numbers.as you know trend of algorithm is toward best combination of C and Sigma. Thanks.

Comment: @user2991243 well that was a typo. I meant 10^-5 to 10^5. :)